Как конвертировать из string в byte
    Random random = new Random();
    byte[] RandomKey = new byte[32];
    string RandomKeyString = "0x";
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        if (random.Next(0, 2) == 0)
        {
            RandomKeyString += random.Next(0, 11).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            RandomKeyString += letter[random.Next(0, 26)];
        }
        if (random.Next(0, 2) == 0)
        {
            RandomKeyString += random.Next(0, 11).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            RandomKeyString += letter[random.Next(0, 26)];
        }
        RandomKey[i] = RandomKeyString;
    }

На выходе из переменной RandomKeyString должно получится что-то похожее на 0xFF или 0x5E нужно записать в переменную RandomKey значение из RandomKeyString.

letter это кто?

И что значит RandomKey[i] = RandomKeyString;?

@eccs0103 Скорее всего, letter = Enumerable.Range(65, 26).Select(s => (char)s).ToArray();

@rotabor: короче (и немного понятнее) было бы var letter = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";. Добавьте .ToArray() по вкусу (но не обязательно).

@VladD "ToCharArray()". Да это всё понятно. Главное, чтобы буковками не набивать. А то ОР мог и "letter[0] = 'A'; ..." напрограммировать, судя по коду.

@rotabor: .ToArray тоже катит, если есть using. А так, да, мог бы :)

Генерировать ключи шифрования с помощью Random категорически нельзя, так как этот PRNG не является криптостойким. Для генерации криптографических артефактов, состоящих из рандомных байт есть RandomNumberGenerator из пространства имён System.Security.Cryptography.
А делается это так:
var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
byte[] randomKey = rng.GetBytes(32);

Получим массив 32 случайных байта.
Если надо вывести в строку в HEX формате:
string hex = Convert.ToHexString(randomKey);

Вообще 0xFF это не 1 байт. Это строка, текстовое представление одного байта. Не путайтесь. 1 байт - это число типа byte от 0 до 255.
Но вообще классы, представляющие алгоритмы шифрования, генерят ключи автоматически. Например:
using Aes aes = Aes.Create();
byte[] key = aes.Key; // это будет новый сгенерированный ключ

Больше примеров тут.

А если прямо отвечать на вопрос, то так:
randomKey[i] = Convert.FromHexString(randomKeyString[2..])[0];

локальные переменные в C# принято называть с маленькой буквы.

"Вообще 0xFF это не 1 байт. Это строка, текстовое представление" одного байта.

@rotabor спасибо, подправил. В будущем такие правки вы можете вносить самостоятельно, я только за.

Да судя по задаче у автора жгучее желание перевода строки в byte array,
Но думаю что тут возможно дело в другом.
Почему то у автора генерация каждого байта не много отходит от стандартов понимания этих данных.

Если есть необходимость сгенерировать псевдослучайной массив байтов, то Random.NextBytes
Если нужно этот массив байтов увидеть т в Hex то ссылка тут

В любом случае генерировать число, потом переводить сгенерированое число в строку а затем пытаться перевести строку в byte. Показывает лишь что автор не много запутался в задаче и потерял мысль которая была изначально.
Но конечно это возможно лишь мои предложения и я ошибаюсь. Но если оно так прошу не судить строго. Пытаюсь лишь помочь автору.
